# How to mount a CD ROM from a USB CD ROM drive on Ubuntu 10.04.3 server

Tags: 10.04, server, usb-drive, cd-drive

I am trying to mount the installation CD rom drive using a USB CD ROM drive on Ubuntu 10.4.3 server to extract additional packages (since I do not have internet active on the server). I plugged the CD rom drive and inserted the CD and I could not find any auto mounting happening. I could not figure out what would be the device name to manually mount. Looks like it is not `/dev/sr0`. Any guidance on mounting a CD on Ubuntu server is appreciated.

**EDIT** Based on the answer from Christopher, here is more information,

```
/0/1                 scsi6       storage     
/0/1/0.0.0           /dev/cdrom  disk        DVD RW AD-7560S
/0/1/0.0.0/0         /dev/cdrom  disk
```

So I guess the device name would be `/dev/cdrom` and I should be able to mount it  with the following command

```
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt
```

I get the following error.

```
mount: /dev/sr0: unknown device
```

However I can automount the CD in my Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop edition.

So please confirm I am recognising the correct `/dev/<dev name>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can glean the device name with "list hardware" (`lshw`):

```
sudo lshw -short
```

Output something like this:

```
H/W path               Device      Class       Description
==========================================================
/0/100/1f.2/0          /dev/cdrom  disk        DVD+-RW GSA-H31L
/0/100/1f.2/1          /dev/sda    disk        750GB ST3750640AS
```

Or maybe pipe to less if there is too much output:

```
sudo lshw -short | less
```

Comment: sudo lshw -short | grep /dev/

Comment: lshw -short | grep /dev/ | awk '{ print $2,"-",$3,"-",$4,"-",$5,"-",$6,"-",$7,"-",$1 }'

Comment: lshw -short | grep /dev/ | awk '{ print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7 }'

Comment: Thanks. Let me try to understand it correct. I get the output like below                                                                /0/1/0.0.0           /dev/cdrom  disk        DVD RW AD-7560S
But I am not successful in mounting cdrom drive as                     sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt

Comment: @Jamess sorry - didn't mean to leave ya hanging - why not? do you get an error message?

Comment: I could not succeed on the same machine. But on another machine sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt worked.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS it is as easy as:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom
```

To unmount, type:

```
$ sudo umount /media/cdrom
```

Comment: This is the most straight-forward way I've seen to do this thus far.

Answer (score 2):

> TRY

```
    sudo su
    mount /dev/scd0 /mnt/{custom-name} -t iso9660
    mount /dev/scd0 /mnt/{custom-name} -t udf
```

> OR

```
mount /dev/sr0 /mnt/{custom-name} -t udf
mount /dev/sr0 /mnt/{custom-name} -t iso9660
```

To Check

```
ls -l /dev/{cd,dvd}*
```

> Output

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 2012-01-29 16:58 /dev/cdrom -> sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 2012-01-29 16:58 /dev/cdrw -> sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 2012-01-29 16:58 /dev/dvd -> sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 2012-01-29 16:58 /dev/dvdrw -> sr0
```

Answer (score 1):

Type `blkid` to see a list of devices attached to your computer.

then type:

```
$ mount /dev/sdc1 cdrom
```

change `sdc1` to the name of your usb stick as listed in blkid. e.g. `sdc0`, `sdc2`, etc